# Google Calendar - iPad compatibility

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, google-calendar

I'm trying to install Google Calendar app on my IPad Air 2.

Couldn't find it in App Store on my IPad. So I found it on a web page
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-calendar/id909319292?mt=8
then I sent this link to my IPad and App Store installed it on IPad but...
It was installed like for IPhone, everything was big and huge so i had to remove it.

It looks like there's no Google Calendar app for IPad. Am I right?

How to install Google Calendar on IPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no separate iPad version, no.

The [iTunes Store Page you linked](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-calendar/id909319292?mt=8) says compatible with iPad, but optimised for iPhone.
That's likely to mean it works, but won't look great.

[image]